# Facebook access_token: how do I get it once the user accepted my app?

Tags: facebook, access-token

When a user visits my site which contains a facebook app the first time, it requires him to allow it and he gets promted to do that, then I get the code which I can convert to an access_token. So far so good.

But how do I get the token once the user has already visited the site?
As long as this token form the first time is active everything is fine. But how do I get another token when the user had already allowed the app a week ago and is only visiting my page again?

Comment: Are you looking for it in any particular language?

Answer (score 4):

Now that Facebook is migrating to Oauth2, the cookie created by the Javascript is different.  I got it to work for me and added it to a fork of the FGraph plugin for Rails - https://github.com/imme5150/fgraph

One of the tricks is that when you request the access_token from the "code" parameter stored in the cookie, you have to pass in "redirect_uri", but you want it to be blank.

Answer (score 3):

On the client-side flow, you can redirect the user to the OAuth dialog with the permissions in the scope parameter. If the user already accepted your App and permissions he will be redirected to your "redirect_uri" with the access_token in the URI fragment, otherwise the needed permissions will be prompt.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream&response_type=token
```

On the server-side flow you should have the "code" so you can redeem it for an access_token on the OAuth endpoint:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URLclient_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_FROM_ABOVE
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I use the cookie method to store the access_token on the user's computer.

```
FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
```

In your facebook.php file you need to set cookieSupport to true then:

```
private $cookieSupport = true;
```

Or use the get_facebook_cookie function found here: [Single sign-on with the JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

The access_token is then stored in a cookie called "fbs_APPID" (**with expire**). If you want the cookie to last more then a couple of hours you need to ask the extended permission 'offline_access':

> Enables your application to perform authorized requests on behalf of the user at any time. By default, most access tokens expire after a short time period to ensure applications only make requests on behalf of the user when the are actively using the application. This permission makes the access token returned by our OAuth endpoint long-lived.

Comment: So the only way to recognize a user is to save the token in a cookie?

Comment: If you inspect the getSession() function inside facebook.php you see that they build the session from $_GET or $_COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this:

```
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getAccessToken/

Answer (score -2):

using php

```
session_start();
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
                'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
                'cookie' => true,
                'domain' => 'example.com'

));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $me = $facebook->api('/me');
        $_SESSION['me'] = $me;
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
        $_SESSION['session'] = $session;

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}
```

you can reference the access_token via $_SESSION['session']['access_token'] within your app,, for more theres tutorials over at fbdevtutorials.com